# Analogue of Python's OrderedDict?

Tags: c#, python, .net

Is there a .net analogue of Python's [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

> An OrderedDict is a dictionary that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the end.

I want this precise behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) behaves like that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic implementation of OrderedDictionary collection in "vanilla" .NET, however, you still can write your own or use existing solutions:

[OrderedDictionary: A generic implementation of IOrderedDictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO/)